# How to list out import statements from a java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a scenario where i need to collect all the import statements using in a java program.

One way which i can think of right now is parsing every file with .java extension, checking if a line starts with import statment and fetching it.

But i want to know if there is any libraries available to do the same or if there is any other efficient methods.

Comment: You need it to find all dependencies in your project?

Comment: grep "^import " *.java, but of course you don't need to `import` to use an external class

Comment: @Manish,, yes kind of . I would like to download all the dependend jar from internet. Its not a maven or gradle project so right now im doing it manually

Comment: @JithinKS but how can you know the associated jar from the import ? it seems to be a very manually work...

Comment: There might be dozens of different jars containing a particular class (for example different versions of the same package). There is no automatic way of choosing which one is required. Maven and Gradle have ways of specifying what is required.

Comment: @SebVb yes its gonna be difficult. But i want the import statements first and then if there is any issues with jar files downloaded , we can do manual validation.